# Postgres Hash Join speed

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have 3 tables which I wish to join using inner joins in Postgres 9.1, reads, devices, and device_patients.  Below is an abbreviated schema for each table.

reads -- ~250,000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE reads
  (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    device_id integer NOT NULL,
    value bigint NOT NULL,
    read_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT reads_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
  )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE reads
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX index_reads_on_device_id
  ON reads
  USING btree
  (device_id );

CREATE INDEX index_reads_on_read_datetime
  ON reads
  USING btree
  (read_datetime );
```

devices -- ~500 rows

```
CREATE TABLE devices
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  serial_number character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE devices
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_devices_on_serial_number
  ON devices
  USING btree
  (serial_number COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );
```

patient_devices -- ~25,000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE patient_devices
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  patient_id integer NOT NULL,
  device_id integer NOT NULL,
  issuance_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  unassignment_datetime timestamp without time zone,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT patient_devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE patient_devices
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX index_patient_devices_on_device_id
  ON patient_devices
  USING btree
  (device_id );

CREATE INDEX index_patient_devices_on_issuance_datetime
  ON patient_devices
  USING btree
  (issuance_datetime );

CREATE INDEX index_patient_devices_on_patient_id
  ON patient_devices
  USING btree
  (patient_id );

CREATE INDEX index_patient_devices_on_unassignment_datetime
  ON patient_devices
  USING btree
  (unassignment_datetime );
```

patients -- ~1,000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE patients
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  first_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  middle_name character varying(50),
  last_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT participants_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE patients
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Here is my abbreviated query.

```
SELECT device_patients.patient_id, serial_number FROM reads
INNER JOIN devices ON devices.id = reads.device_id
INNER JOIN patient_devices ON device_patients.device_id = devices.id
WHERE (reads.read_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 10:30:01.000000' AND '2013-05-18 03:03:42')
AND (read_datetime > issuance_datetime) AND ((unassignment_datetime IS NOT NULL AND read_datetime < unassignment_datetime) OR
(unassignment_datetime IS NULL))
GROUP BY serial_number, patient_devices.patient_id LIMIT 10
```

Ultimately this will be a small part of a larger query (without the LIMIT, I only added the limit to prove to myself that the long runtime was not due to returning a bunch of rows), however I've done a bunch of experimenting and determined that this is the slow part of the larger query.  When I run EXPLAIN ANALYZE on this query I get the following output (also viewable [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/1LG))

```
Limit  (cost=156442.31..156442.41 rows=10 width=13) (actual time=2815.435..2815.441 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=156442.31..159114.89 rows=267258 width=13) (actual time=2815.432..2815.437 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1157.78..151455.79 rows=997304 width=13) (actual time=30.930..2739.164 rows=250150 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (devices.device_id = devices.id)
              Join Filter: ((reads.read_datetime > patient_devices.issuance_datetime) AND (((patient_devices.unassignment_datetime IS NOT NULL) AND (reads.read_datetime < patient_devices.unassignment_datetime)) OR (patient_devices.unassignment_datetime IS NULL)))
              ->  Seq Scan on reads  (cost=0.00..7236.94 rows=255396 width=12) (actual time=0.035..64.433 rows=255450 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((read_datetime >= '2012-01-01 10:30:01'::timestamp without time zone) AND (read_datetime <= '2013-05-18 03:03:42'::timestamp without time zone))
              ->  Hash  (cost=900.78..900.78 rows=20560 width=37) (actual time=30.830..30.830 rows=25015 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1755kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=19.90..900.78 rows=20560 width=37) (actual time=0.776..20.551 rows=25015 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (patient_devices.device_id = devices.id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on patient_devices  (cost=0.00..581.93 rows=24893 width=24) (actual time=0.014..7.867 rows=25545 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((unassignment_datetime IS NOT NULL) OR (unassignment_datetime IS NULL))
                          ->  Hash  (cost=13.61..13.61 rows=503 width=13) (actual time=0.737..0.737 rows=503 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on devices  (cost=0.00..13.61 rows=503 width=13) (actual time=0.016..0.466 rows=503 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (entity_id = 2)
Total runtime: 2820.392 ms
```

My question is how do I speed this up?  Right now I'm running this on my Windows machine for testing, but ultimately it will be deployed on Ubuntu, will that make a difference?  Any insight into why this takes 2 seconds would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

It has been suggested that the LIMIT might be altering the query plan.  [Here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/LMB) is the same query without the LIMIT.  The slow part still appears to be the Hash Join.

Also, here are the relevant tuning parameters.  Again I'm only testing this on Windows now, and I don't know what effect this would have on a Linux machine

shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 4GB
work_mem = 256MB
random_page_cost = 2.0

Here are the statistics for the reads table

```
Statistic   Value
Sequential Scans    130
Sequential Tuples Read  28865850
Index Scans 283630
Index Tuples Fetched    141421907
Tuples Inserted 255450
Tuples Updated  0
Tuples Deleted  0
Tuples HOT Updated  0
Live Tuples 255450
Dead Tuples 0
Heap Blocks Read    20441
Heap Blocks Hit 3493033
Index Blocks Read   8824
Index Blocks Hit    4840210
Toast Blocks Read   
Toast Blocks Hit    
Toast Index Blocks Read 
Toast Index Blocks Hit  
Last Vacuum 2013-05-20 09:23:03.782-07
Last Autovacuum 
Last Analyze    2013-05-20 09:23:03.91-07
Last Autoanalyze    2013-05-17 19:01:44.075-07
Vacuum counter  1
Autovacuum counter  0
Analyze counter 1
Autoanalyze counter 6
Table Size  27 MB
Toast Table Size    none
Indexes Size    34 MB
```

Here are the statistics for the devices table

```
Statistic   Value
Sequential Scans    119
Sequential Tuples Read  63336
Index Scans 1053935
Index Tuples Fetched    1053693
Tuples Inserted 609
Tuples Updated  0
Tuples Deleted  0
Tuples HOT Updated  0
Live Tuples 609
Dead Tuples 0
Heap Blocks Read    32
Heap Blocks Hit 1054553
Index Blocks Read   32
Index Blocks Hit    2114305
Toast Blocks Read   
Toast Blocks Hit    
Toast Index Blocks Read 
Toast Index Blocks Hit  
Last Vacuum 
Last Autovacuum 
Last Analyze    
Last Autoanalyze    2013-05-17 19:02:49.692-07
Vacuum counter  0
Autovacuum counter  0
Analyze counter 0
Autoanalyze counter 2
Table Size  48 kB
Toast Table Size    none
Indexes Size    128 kB
```

Here are the statistics for the patient_devices table

```
Statistic   Value
Sequential Scans    137
Sequential Tuples Read  3065400
Index Scans 853990
Index Tuples Fetched    46143763
Tuples Inserted 25545
Tuples Updated  24936
Tuples Deleted  0
Tuples HOT Updated  0
Live Tuples 25547
Dead Tuples 929
Heap Blocks Read    1959
Heap Blocks Hit 6099617
Index Blocks Read   1077
Index Blocks Hit    2462681
Toast Blocks Read   
Toast Blocks Hit    
Toast Index Blocks Read 
Toast Index Blocks Hit  
Last Vacuum 
Last Autovacuum 2013-05-17 19:01:44.576-07
Last Analyze    
Last Autoanalyze    2013-05-17 19:01:44.697-07
Vacuum counter  0
Autovacuum counter  6
Analyze counter 0
Autoanalyze counter 6
Table Size  2624 kB
Toast Table Size    none
Indexes Size    5312 kB
```

Below is the full query that I'm trying to speed up.  The smaller query is indeed faster, but I was unable to make my full query faster which is reproduced below.  As suggested, I added 4 new indices, UNIQUE(device_id, issuance_datetime), UNIQUE(device_id, issuance_datetime), UNIQUE(patient_id, unassignment_datetime), UNIQUE(patient_id, unassignment_datetime)

```
SELECT 
first_name
, last_name
, MAX(max_read) AS read_datetime
, SUM(value) AS value
, serial_number
FROM (
    SELECT
    pa.first_name
    , pa.last_name
    , value
    , first_value(de.serial_number) OVER(PARTITION BY pa.id ORDER BY re.read_datetime DESC) AS serial_number -- I'm not sure if this is a good way to do this, but I don't know of another way
    , re.read_datetime
    , MAX(re.read_datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY pd.id) AS max_read
    FROM reads re
    INNER JOIN devices de ON de.id = re.device_id
    INNER JOIN patient_devices pd ON pd.device_id = de.id
        AND re.read_datetime >= pd.issuance_datetime
        AND re.read_datetime < COALESCE(pd.unassignment_datetime , 'infinity'::timestamp)
    INNER JOIN patients pa ON pa.id = pd.patient_id
    WHERE re.read_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 10:30:01' AND '2013-05-18 03:03:42'
) AS foo WHERE read_datetime = max_read
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, serial_number ORDER BY value desc
LIMIT 10
```

Sorry for not posting this earlier, but I thought this query would be too complicated, and was trying to simply the problem, but apparently I still can't figure it out.  It seems like it would be a LOT quicker if I could limit the results returned by the nested select using the max_read variable, but according to numerous sources, that isn't allowed in Postgres.

Comment: Please add the **real** DDLs for your tables, including keys and indexes.

Comment: maybe its a typo, but youre missing an index in table `patient_devices` on the `device_id`

Comment: The query is effectively selecting all the rows (the date range is not very selective, as it appears) orders them and keeps the top 10 and throws away the rest. BTW Why are you using a `GROUP BY` but not any aggragate function? Did you mean `ORDER BY` ? (not that it matters ...)

Comment: I just updated my query to show the real creation scripts with all the indices that I have.

Comment: Adding a limit is potentially going to change your query execution plan, as the optimiser knows that only few rows now need to be returned -- in general it's going to promote the use of index-based access methods.

Comment: I have added another link to show the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output without the LIMIT clause as well.  The slow part still appears to be the Hash Join.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: The devices table has both a surrogate key and a natural key (serial_no ) with a unique constraint. Merging on one and ordering on the other (+LIMIT) will be painful in any case, IMHO) To the OP: please try the query with a smaller date interval instead ot the limit. Your interval appears to cover everything in the dataset. BTW do you have statistics?

Comment: @wildplasser, what statistics are you looking for?

Comment: @wildplasser: I meant to use a GROUP BY instead of an ORDER BY.  If I don't use the GROUP BY then the query plan changes and the Hash Join isn't executed (and the query takes ~ 100 ms).  However, in my full query I have to use a GROUP BY, hence why I'm showing it here.

Comment: Statistics, like those maintained by `VACUUM ANALYZE <tablename>;` Plus the relevant tuning parameters { shared_buffers, effective_cache_size, work_mem, random_page_cost}

Comment: @wildplasser: I just ran the query again without the LIMIT or GROUP BY clauses and it still has a very long running Hash Join.  I think ultimately that is my problem.  I was really hoping that I was missing some kind of index, or I could change my postgres config file to help alleviate the problem.

Comment: @wildplasser: I've added the tuning parameters and statistics.

Comment: `work_mem = 256MB random_page_cost = 2.0` Try setting work_mem to a sane value (lower) and/or random_page_cost to a lower value (~ 1.2). If you have usable indices (and valid astatistics) they will be used. Unless the query needs all the rows (which I fear it does)

Comment: When I set the work_mem to 5MB and random_page_cost to 1.2 the query now takes ~3.1 seconds, with the Hash Join still being very slow.

Comment: I've added more information about the full query I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI: sanitised query:

```
SELECT pd.patient_id
        , de.serial_number
FROM reads re
INNER JOIN devices de ON de.id = re.device_id
INNER JOIN patient_devices pd ON pd.device_id = de.id
        AND re.read_datetime >= pd.issuance_datetime -- changed this from '>' to '>='
        AND (re.read_datetime < pd.unissuance_datetime OR pd.unissuance_datetime IS NULL)
WHERE re.read_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 10:30:01.000000' AND '2013-05-18 03:03:42'
GROUP BY de.serial_number, pd.patient_id 
LIMIT 10
   ;
```

UPDATE: without the original typos:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pd.patient_id
        , de.serial_number
FROM reads re
INNER JOIN devices de ON de.id = re.device_id
INNER JOIN patient_devices pd ON pd.device_id = de.id
        AND re.read_datetime >= pd.issuance_datetime
        AND (re.read_datetime < pd.unassignment_datetime OR pd.unassignment_datetime IS NULL)
WHERE re.read_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 10:30:01.000000' AND '2013-05-18 03:03:42'
GROUP BY de.serial_number, pd.patient_id
LIMIT 10
  ;
```

UPDATE: this is about 6 times as fast here (on synthetic data, and with a slightly altered data model)

```
-- Modified data model + synthetic data:
CREATE TABLE devices
( id serial NOT NULL
, serial_number character varying(20) NOT NULL
-- , created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
-- , updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
, UNIQUE (serial_number)
) ;

CREATE TABLE reads
  -- ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY -- You don't need this surrogate key
  (  device_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES devices (id)
  ,  value bigint NOT NULL
  ,  read_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  -- ,  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  -- ,  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY ( device_id, read_datetime)
  ) ;



CREATE TABLE patient_devices
-- ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY -- You don't need this surrogate key
( patient_id integer NOT NULL -- REFERENCES patients (id)
, device_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES devices(id)
, issuance_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
, unassignment_datetime timestamp without time zone
-- , created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
-- , updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (device_id, issuance_datetime)
, UNIQUE (device_id, unassignment_datetime)
) ;


-- CREATE INDEX index_patient_devices_on_issuance_datetime ON patient_devices (device_id, unassignment_datetime );
-- may need some additional indices later

-- devices -- ~500 rows
INSERT INTO devices(serial_number) SELECT 'No_' || gs::text FROM generate_series(1,500) gs;

-- reads -- ~100K rows
INSERT INTO reads(device_id, read_datetime, value)
SELECT  de.id, gs
        , (random()*1000000)::bigint
FROM devices  de
JOIN generate_series('2012-01-01', '2013-05-01' , '1 hour' ::interval) gs
        ON random() < 0.02;

-- patient_devices -- ~25,000 rows
INSERT INTO patient_devices(device_id, issuance_datetime, patient_id)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (re.device_id, read_datetime)
        re.device_id, read_datetime, pa
FROM generate_series(1,100) pa
JOIN reads re
        ON random() < 0.01;

        -- close the open intervals
UPDATE patient_devices dst
SET unassignment_datetime = src.issuance_datetime
FROM patient_devices src
WHERE src.device_id = dst.device_id
AND src.issuance_datetime > dst.issuance_datetime
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM patient_devices nx
        WHERE nx.device_id = src.device_id
        AND nx.issuance_datetime > dst.issuance_datetime
        AND nx.issuance_datetime < src.issuance_datetime
        )
        ;

VACUUM ANALYZE patient_devices;
VACUUM ANALYZE devices;
VACUUM ANALYZE reads;


-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pd.patient_id
        , de.serial_number
        --, COUNT (*) AS zcount
FROM reads re
INNER JOIN devices de ON de.id = re.device_id
INNER JOIN patient_devices pd ON pd.device_id = de.id
        AND re.read_datetime >= pd.issuance_datetime
        AND re.read_datetime < COALESCE(pd.unassignment_datetime , 'infinity'::timestamp)
WHERE re.read_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 10:30:01' AND '2013-05-18 03:03:42'
GROUP BY de.serial_number, pd.patient_id
LIMIT 10
        ;
```

Comment: How will this help me?

Comment: It might not help you, but it might help others who try to help you (and will probably start by exactly the same rewrite)

Comment: OK, well hopefully it does ;)

Comment: I've updated my question to include my full query.  Your suggestions did indeed speed up the original query I posted.  I've tried to incorporate your suggestions into the full query but am not seeing the speed ups.

Comment: Most of my answer is not about the query *per se* but about the data model: I removed useless (IMHO) surrogate keys, and added sane (IMHO) foreign key constraints. The underlying problem is still a *3 dimentional* triangle model: {device, patient, datetime} are a 2/3 dimentional PK on your junction table `patient_devices`. It might indicate a BCNF-violation, but that would depend on the actual contents of the data.

Comment: I added an additional index that I see that I forgot, and now the fully query is down to about 1.2 seconds.  Honestly, I'm not a DBA, and I'm learning a lot about DBs now.  I think I'll have to read more about BCNF (as I have never heard of it).  I was under the impression that using an intermediary table for a many-to-many relationship was a common practice.  If this is not the industry standard, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

look at the parts of the `analyze` report where you see `Seq Scan`.

for example this parts could use some indexes:

```
 Seq Scan on patient_devices - > unassignment_datetime
 Seq Scan on devices -> entity_id
 Seq Scan on reads - > read_datetime
```

about `read_datetime`: it is possible to create a specific index for mathematical equation like `>` and `<=`, which will come handy. i dont know the syntax for it, though

Comment: Those also popped out at me, and I have btree indices for all of them, so I'm not sure what else I can do.  However, it would seem that all the time is spent in the Hash Join.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure which index function you are referring to.  After reading the documentation, I thought a b-tree was the type of index I wanted, but if that isn't true, I'd love to know which type I do want.